# Google Script for Gmail to Delete Emails With *Only* the Specified Label

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to find a way to target emails which have only one label. I want to delete messages which have a specific label and are older than 2 weeks. However, I want the script to ignore any emails which have additional labels besides the specified label.

For example an email with label **'Subscriptions'** gets deleted, but an email with label **'Subscriptions'** *AND* **'Keep!'** will not.

The version I have currently will delete any email with the specified label regardless of any other labels applied.

I am using the publicly available [Gmail Cleaning Robot script](https://medium.com/@fw3d/a-cleaning-robot-for-your-gmail-inbox-f44c01306ea2#.2gcwm8sqs) by [Fred Mouniguet](https://medium.com/@fw3d) as my base.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function gmailCleaningRobot() {

var delayDays = 14; // will only impact emails more than 2 weeks old
var maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays); // what was the date at that time?

// Get all the threads labeled 'Subscriptions'
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Subscriptions");
var threads = label.getThreads(0, 100);

// we archive all the threads if they're unread AND older than the limit we set in delayDays
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate && threads[i].isUnread())
{
threads[i].moveToTrash();
}
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using the [getLabels](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getLabels()) on your thread instance in your if statement.

try the following.

```
if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate && threads[i].isUnread() 
    && threads.getLabels().length == 1)
```